# How do you prove $\prod_{i=0}^n(1+2^{2^i})=2^{2^{n+1}}-1$ using induction?

Tags: proof-verification, induction, exponentiation, products

For a homework assignment, I am being asked to find and prove (by induction) a simple formula for $\prod_{i=0}^n(1+2^{2^i})$. Plugging in a few small values of $n$ shows that the formula is $2^{2^{n+1}}-1$. However, when I tried to prove it using induction, I ran into some issues. Here is what I have so far:

We will prove using induction that $P(n)$ is true for all positive integers $n$, where $P(n)$ is true exactly when $\prod_{i=0}^n(1+2^{2^i})=2^{2^{n+1}}-1$ and false otherwise.

Base case:

When $n=0$, the left side of $P(n)$ is

$\prod_{i=0}^0(1+2^{2^i})=1+2^{2^0}=1+2^1=3$

and the right side is

$2^{2^{0+1}}-1=2^2-1=3$

Both sides are equal, so $P(n)$ holds for $n=0$.

Induction step:

Let $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and suppose that $P(n)$ is true for $n=k$.

We want to show that $P(n)$ is also true for $n=k+1$; that is, we want to show that $\prod_{i=0}^{k+1}(1+2^{2^i})=2^{2^{k+2}}-1$.

$\prod_{i=0}^{k+1}(1+2^{2^i})$

$=(1+2^{2^{k+1}})\prod_{i=0}^{k}(1+2^{2^i})\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$factoring out the $k+1$ term

$=(1+2^{2^{k+1}})(2^{2^{k+1}}-1)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$ by the inductive hypothesis

$=(2^{2^{k+1}})^2-1\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$ expanding the above

$=2^{2^{2(k+1)}}-1\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$ by properties of exponents

$=2^{2^{2k+2}}-1$

However, we wanted to show that $\prod_{i=0}^{k+1}(1+2^{2^i})=2^{2^{k+2}}-1$, not $2^{2^{2k+2}}-1$. Clearly these two quantities are not equal. Can anyone spot the bug in this proof? Or perhaps the formula is wrong in the first place?

Thanks

Comment: $\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (1+x^{2^i}) = \sum_{m=0}^{2^k-1} x^m$ (any integer $< 2^k$ is a sum of distinct powers of $2$ in a unique way)

Comment: @Sil Sorry, that was a typo. I want $2^{2^{k+2}}-1$, but I have $2^{2^{2k+2}}-1$.

Comment: I see, well $(2^{2^{k+1}})^2 \neq 2^{2^{2(k+1)}}$, as the answers show. Instead $(2^{2^{k+1}})^2=2^{2\cdot 2^{k+1}}=2^{2^{k+2}}$

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake just before the last step("by property of exponent").
 Note that 
$$ 2*(2^j) = 2^{(j+1)} $$. And $$ (a^b)^c = a^{bc} $$ not $a^b^c$

Answer (score 1):

$$  (2^{2^{k+1}})^2 = 2^{2^{k+1}} \cdot 2^{2^{k+1}} = 2^{2^{k+1}+2^{k+1}} = 2^{2 \cdot 2^{k+1}} = 2^{2^{k+2}}  \text{.}  $$

Answer (score 1):

Induction step:

$$\left(2^{2^{n+1}}-1\right)\left(1+2^{2^{n+1}}\right)=2^{2^{n+1}}+\left(2^{2^{n+1}}\right)^2-1-2^{2^{n+1}}=2^{2^{n+1}\cdot2}-1=2^{2^{n+2}}-1$$

Applied rule:$$\left(a^b\right)^c=a^{bc}$$